# How to retrieve BDC Identity from External List programmatically?

Tags: powershell, client-object-model, bcs, external-list, bdc

I need to do a lookup on an External List (in SharePoint Online - Office 365) to retrieve the value of the BDC Identity.  BCS is talking to an OData web service.

(I'm not a Visual Studio guy), so been trying to make it work with SharePoint hosted app (CSOM) as well as CSOM in Powershell.

Does anyone know any way to accomplish this?

I am importing documents in from another system and need to programmatically map up the database connection.  I want to query the External List, get the BDC Identity column for a unique ID number, then set the BDC_ID in the document library.

Comment: this link might help you.https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Create-ffc9af9f

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Create-an-33c2b211

Comment: that link seems to focus on creating the external list , i need to query an already existing external list